# Vue Component- > Export default ... was not found in

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

i want to create a dashboard as a component. but i always get this error in my cmd

- "export 'default' (imported as 'DashboardLayoutComponent') was not found in '@syncfusion/ej2-vue-layouts'

does anyone know how i can fix this issue?

Comment: Please let us know whether this occurs with Vue 2 or Vue 3 project. 

For reference, a sample with Vue 3 rendering Dashboard Layout is attached in the below link.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-forked-i4bt6?file=/src/App.vue

Refer to the following UG link for getting started with Dashboard Layout in Vue 3.

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/documentation/dashboard-layout/getting-started-vue-3/

If the issue persists, please share your package.json code to proceed further with this.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/documentation/dashboard-layout/getting-started/#using-vueuse), it appears `DashboardLayoutComponent` is a [named export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export), thus you must import it as such:

```js
import { DashboardLayoutPlugin } from '@syncfuion/ej2-vue-layouts';
```

Note the `{ }`.

Answer (score 0):

vue component should be register with `default` example:

```
import { ComponentA } from './ComponentA.vue' // if exported as normal
// import ComponentA from './ComponentA.vue' // if exported as default

export default { // component registoring with default
  components: {
    ComponentA
  },
  // code
}
```